# In bash, what does dot command ampersand do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to understand a bash script I'm supposed to be maintaining and got stuck. The command is of this form:

```
. $APP_LOCATION/somescript.sh param1 param2 &
```

The line is not being called in a loop, not is any return code bening sent back to the calling script from somescript.sh

I know that the "." will make the process run in the same shell. But "&" will spawn off a different process.

That sounds contradictory. What's is really happening here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The script is running in a background process, but it is a subshell, not a separately-invoked interpreter as it would be without the dot.

That is to say -- the current interpreter forks and then begins running the command (sourcing the script). As such, it inherits shell variables, not just environment variables.

Otherwise the new script's interpreter would be invoked via an `execv()` call, which would replace the current interpreter with a new one. That's usually the right thing, because it provides more flexibility -- you can't run anything but a script written for the same shell with `.` or `source`, after all, whereas starting a new interpreter means that your other script could be rewritten in Python, Perl, a compiled binary, etc without its callers needing to change.

(This is part of why scripts intended to be exec'd, as opposed to than libraries meant to be sourced, should not have filename extensions -- and part of why `bash` libraries should be `.bash`, not `.sh`, such that inaccurate information isn't provided about what kind of interpreter they can be sourced into).

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

```
. $APP_LOCATION/somescript.sh param1 param2 &
```

This sources a script as a background job in the current shell.

### Sourcing a Script

In Bash, using `.` is equivalent to the [source builtin]. The help for the source builtin says (in part):

```
$ help source
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
```

In other words, it reads in your Bash script and evaluates it in the current shell rather than in a sub-shell. This is often important to give a script access to unexported variables.

### Background Jobs

The ampersand executes the script in the background using [job control](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html#Job-Control-Basics). In this case, while the sourced script is *evaluated* in the context of the current shell, it is *executed* in a separate process that can be managed using [job control builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html).

Comment: One quibble -- `source` is a bash-only alias for the POSIX-standard `.`, rather than the other way around (which this could potentially be read to imply).

Comment: ...also, "In other words, it reads in your Bash script and evaluates it in the current shell rather than in a sub-shell" is somewhat misleading. A new shell created by a fork/exec sequence is not a subshell; a subshell [as involved in pipelines, `$()` operators, `(...)`, etc] is created by `fork()` alone, with no following `exec()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your thought-provoking comment! The Bash manual actually says "source" is a `synonym for .` so it's not an alias in the typical sense of the term. Your other points are well-taken, though; my answer is approaching the question from a *practical* point of view, rather than looking at the system-level calls. fork(2) creates "an  exact  duplicate of the calling process," which a shell *user* should experience as evaluation within the child's parent process, especially since the child can read/write variables in its parent's address space.

Comment: That's actually incorrect -- unlike a thread, a new process created with `fork()` has its own _copy_ of memory, rather than access to the exact same pages. (An operating system may play copy-on-write tricks as an implementation detail to avoid needing to allocate the full amount up-front, but the point is that other than SHM segments and mmap contents created with appropriate options, memory is _not_ shared between parents and children).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fork(2) says: "The  entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child[.]" In the end, sourcing allows changes to the variables in the current shell; how this is implemented under the hood shouldn't matter to the shell user, which is why I think examining system calls is the wrong way to answer the question.

Comment: "replicated" doesn't mean that your virtual memory mappings point to the same physical pages; it means they map to pages which appear to have the same contents as of the point in time when the fork call occurs. When not understanding the underlying implementation means you give people blatantly incorrect answers about behavior, the differences matter.

Comment: To be a little more clear, by the way -- "subshells" inherit shell variables. Subprocesses which happen to be shells (but were invoked via an exec call) don't. Thus, claiming that the alternative to dotting a script in is a subshell misleads about behavior, and leads to misunderstanding other documentation which uses the terms of the art in their canonical manner.

Comment: Coming back and reviewing this years later, it remains factually incorrect. Above and beyond what I wrote earlier, the claim that dotting a script in the background performs "evaluation" and "execution" stages in two separate processes is flatly false; parsing of the dotted-in file happens in the same subshell that executes its contents.